# Edit SVGs inside objects that comes from cross-origin source

Tags: javascript, svg, cross-domain, postmessage, object-tag

I'm trying to execute this code ...

```
(function () {
    var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object'),
        objectsLength = objects.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < objectsLength; i++) {
        var svg = objects[i].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
        svg.setAttribute("width", "100%");
    }
})();
```

I'm trying to force a width of "100%" to SVGs inside ojbect tags.
Althought that code works on "localhost" it doesn't work on the server because of "cros-origin" security issue.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLObjectElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.example.org" from accessing a cross-origin frame

My search resulted in using `window.postMessage`, But I can't get my head around how to use it in this case.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: host everything on the same server.

Comment: We (as a company) own both servers, the objects come from a sub-domain "images.example.org", and it's not my decision to move everything to the same domain.

Comment: I guess you'll have to implement CORS on the servers since you own them both.

Comment: Can't I do it using "window.postMessage"?

Comment: Browsers don't generally allow you to work around their security restrictions, otherwise there would be no point in having them would there?

Comment: If you use `window.postMessage()`, you have to add an event listener `window.addEventListener("message", ...)` to your target image file. If you have to change that file to add a script, you could just as easily set the `width` attribute - so what is the point in that approach?

Comment: It's a dynamically generated SVG images, they are over a thousand images, So editing each image manually is not an option.